# Erb params in yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I'm trying to insert on a result page a dynamic title and description depending on the search input, in my Ruby on rails 5 app.

My title and description on the search result page, are translated and look like so on the erb page:

```
<% title t('application.titleserv') %>

<% meta t('application.descripserv') %>
```

Both, my title and description, are translated in yml files in config/locales

On the erb page, i can get the search result params with:

```
<%= params[:search]%>
```

I want to add the params search to the title and description, by adding it into the yaml file or in the erb file.

If anyone have an idea let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template:

```
t('application.titleserv', search: params[:search] )
```

Yml file

```
titleserv: "blablabla %{search} blabla"
```

that's what you're looking for ?

Comment: Yes thanks a lot you make me save time!!, i was turning around that solution for hours